# Force sending delete requests in AzureAD SCIM

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I am provisioning a SCIM client from AzureAD. Create/update works fine. When a user is removed from AzureAD recycle bin (hard-delete), I also receive delete requests.
Now I have issues with soft-delete.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/how-provisioning-works#de-provisioning) states:

> If one of the above four events occurs and the target application does not support soft deletes, the provisioning service will send a DELETE request to permanently delete the user from the app.

How does AAD know if the target app supports soft deletes? In my current setup, I have not configured any `active` or `IsSoftDeleted` attribute mapping. So I would expect AAD to send me DELETE requests.

Well it turns out AAD "thinks" that I support this feature, because it tries to soft-delete my users (through update, i.e. PATCH requests). This is not what I want, I need DELETE all the time, as written in the documentation.

How can I achieve this?

(The `SkipOutOfScopeDeletions` flag does not work either. I was expecting it to convert soft-deletes to DELETE requests, but apparently it only skips soft-deletes completely. No conversion.)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @GuidoNeele I opened a ticket at Microsoft, here is their answer: "The behavior described in the article is for gallery apps where we [Microsoft] have built the integration. For those integrations, if the app does not support soft delete, we will build it to do hard delete. This is not configurable on the generic SCIM app." So basically there is no solution for me, as I'm using the generic SCIM connector, I receive soft-deletes most of the time.